# Allow customers to customize opencart products

Tags: php, e-commerce, opencart

Hi I've been struggling to find a plugin to suite my needs.

I am working on an ecommerce site for someone and they basically want a store which sells christmas products. They sell personalised christmas decorations and they want to be able to allow customers to type into a form field before adding each product to their cart which will work as a note to seller.

An example is that there is a product of a penguin holding a sign and and above the add to cart button will be a small field form which says Name and the customer can type their name in so when the order goes through my client can see what name they want added onto the sign.

I'm not locked down to OpenCart so if this sort of feature is available in anything else such as OsCommerce then that is always a possibility.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is already a standard feature of opencart. Simply create an option with the type text and then assign that option to your product

Comment: Oh my god I'm such an idiot haha, I thought that was probably what that bit meant but I didn't realise you were bound to a set of categories. Thanks :)